# How to pass variable as property name to access value of other object in angular 2 interpolation operator?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I want to pass variable as property of other object and access the value of that property in angular 2 interpolation operator.

I have two objects as below:

```
obj1 = { "abc":"123", "xyz":"456", "pqr":"789"}
obj2 = { "123":"name1", "456":"name2", "789":"name3"}
```

And I want to display name1, name2 and name3 based on obj1 property names so I tried below solution but value is not getting displayed in HTML.

```
{{obj2["'+obj1.abc+'"]}}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried a method in your component to return the results?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make a string. The expression in the `[]` will be evaluated and use it's value as a property name.

```
{{ obj2[obj1.abc] }}
```

Example

```js
const obj1 = { "abc":"123", "xyz":"456", "pqr":"789"};
const obj2 = { "123":"name1", "456":"name2", "789":"name3"};

console.log( obj2[obj1.abc] );
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html >
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    // Here the array would be your response.text:
     $scope.obj1 = { "abc":"123", "xyz":"456", "pqr":"789"};
    $scope.obj2 = { "123":"name1", "456":"name2", "789":"name3"};

}]);
   
    </script>
  </head>
  <body >
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in obj1">
            {{x}} | {{obj2[x]}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```